# Implementing Regex In Play Application Routes

Tags: java, nginx, playframework, routes

I want to implement regex for routes in play application in below format, which is not working.

```
Expected URL: /en-us/shops/boys
Routes URL: /shops/*path
```

The above route is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the code in question.  What result do you get, and what result do you want to get instead?

Comment: @markspace question is about implementing regex in routes file of play application. when user try to hit /en-us/shops/boys it has to go the registered route which is /shops/*path but it is not. It is going to the registered route only if i try with /shops/boys

Comment: `/en-us/shops/boys` does not match `/shops/*path` (there is an extra `/en-us`)